# Template class using Gold Parser and the Klimstra engine

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, lalr, gold-parser

I'm using Klimstra's VB.NET template from the "Create skeleton program" of the GOLD parser but the resulting template has methods with the overrides keyword and inherits from `TemplateParser`..

Am I supposed to create the TemplateParser class or is there a tool to create it? I thought that the "create skeleton" function created a template that I was supposed to inherit and provide implementation to the "MustOverride" methods but now I don't know.

I'm following a tutorial that makes it look like we have to create it using a tool but I'm not sure. I don't know if the tutorial is very outdated (it's dated 2005) and the GOLD parser changed this mechanism. This is the tutorial I'm following: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/IntrotoGoldParser.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I were just looking into this topic a your link to the article really helped me.
I figured out that in the source files provided with the artictle there are two file with extension .pgt. These are templates for GOLD Code generator. Yout have to copy them into your GOLD installation folder -> Templates and to use them both when you are creating the skeleton program.

I hope this is helpful.